# How do I parse the middle string between two characters (dashes )in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can parse the first and last section of the samples below (the sql works for last section). I need to parse each part into it's own column, but I may not know how many dashes are in the string.

```
select right(doc, CHARINDEX('-', reverse(doc))- 1) as Document
from table
```

For Doc value `Loan-LDOC-Commercial`, it should parse to three columns.

For Doc value `Loan-LDOC-COLL-Assignment` it should parse to four columns.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? They all have different string functions, though `CHARINDEX()` is maybe a clue toward SQL Server)

Comment: sql server 2008, sorry forgot that tag....I guess I'm doing a reverse concatenate on the dashes

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of delimited fields -> columns?

Comment: I wouldn't parse this into variable number of columns. How will your program logic read this? How many columns max? I believe it would be better if tokens are parsed to rows, like `row1=(Loan-LDOC-Commercial, Loan)`, `row2=(Loan-LDOC-Commercial, LDOC)` etc.

Comment: no fixed length.  I have to pull this into a report for the business so I just created a select statement, but they want it parse out...I can do it in excel, but I'd rather do it in my query.

Comment: What kind of reporting engine? Most of the contemporary reporting engines support matrix (in SSRS tablix), that can render a table with variable row count. However, input for rendering such matrix is a fixed-length table, like `data(x, y)`.

Comment: If row 1 has 2 dashes and row 2 has 5 dashes, how many columns would you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following table function for this purpose. The comments contain an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.funcSplitToTable
/*
   Split a string into parts base on a separation character to produce
   a table that has one column containing the results of the split.

   EXAMPLE:
      SELECT * FROM dbo.funcSplitToTable( '~', 'MAINT~12221~10001~10/25/2004~CANCELLED~1' )
      SELECT * FROM dbo.funcSplitToTable( '~', '' )
      SELECT * FROM dbo.funcSplitToTable( '~', NULL )
      SELECT * FROM dbo.funcSplitToTable( NULL, 'MAINT~12221~10001~10/25/2004~CANCELLED~1' )
      SELECT * FROM dbo.funcSplitToTable( '', 'MAINT~12221~10001~10/25/2004~CANCELLED~1' )

   RETURN:
      Table with one column containing resulting strings.
*/
(
    @strSearch       AS varchar(255)            -- String to search for.
   ,@strText         AS varchar(MAX )           -- Text to search for string.
)
RETURNS @tblResult TABLE (
    rowid       int NOT NULL identity(1,1),
    result      varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (rowid)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @iLastPos        int
          , @iPos            int
          , @lngSearch       int
          , @lngText         int
          , @lngSubstring    int
          , @strResult       varchar(MAX)
          ;
    IF @strText IS NULL RETURN ;
    SET @lngText = LEN(@strText + 'X') - 1 ;

    IF @strSearch IS NULL SET @strSearch = '' ;
    SET @lngSearch = LEN(@strSearch + 'X') - 1 ;

    IF @lngSearch <= 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tblResult
        SELECT @strText AS result
        ;
        RETURN ;
    END

    SET @strResult    = NULL ;
    SET @iLastPos     = 1 ;
    SET @iPos         = CHARINDEX( @strSearch, @strText ) ;

    WHILE @iPos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @lngSubstring = @iPos - @iLastPos ;
        IF @lngSubstring > 0
            INSERT INTO @tblResult
            SELECT SUBSTRING( @strText, @iLastPos, @lngSubstring ) AS result
            ;
        SET @iLastPos  = @iPos + @lngSearch ;
        SET @iPos      = CHARINDEX( @strSearch, @strText, @iLastPos ) ;
    END

    SET @lngSubstring = @lngSearch + @lngText - @iLastPos ;
    IF @lngSubstring > 0
        INSERT INTO @tblResult
        SELECT SUBSTRING( @strText, @iLastPos, @lngSubstring ) AS result
        ;
    RETURN ;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you worked with CLR procedures you can do this easily using C# or and .NET language because it has a lot better syntax for that.

```
string s = "Loan-LDOC-COLL-Assignment";
string []split = s.Split(new char[] {'-'} , StringSplitOptions.None);
```

[Here’s](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/) a tutorial on how to create CLR procedure and add it to database.